# Old attachment disappears new one shows up

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

```
private List<string> arrayList = new List<string>();
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        {

            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {

                    foreach (string currentAttachmentUrl in item.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (!arrayList.Contains(currentAttachmentUrl))
                        {

                            hp.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            hp.Text = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + currentAttachmentUrl;
                            hp.NavigateUrl = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + currentAttachmentUrl;
                            arrayList.Add(currentAttachmentUrl);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // add to the repeater 
                e.Item.Controls.Add(hp);

            }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also post how you are binding the Repeater ??

Comment: SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query =
                    string.Format(
                        "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");


                query.RowLimit = 10;
                query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                

                Repeater1.DataSource = items;
                Repeater1.DataBind();